# node.js cannot find 'neo4j' module (Thingdom)

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

After many tries, I am unnable to connect node.js to Neo4j installed in my computer. I am able to access both separately, and both work fine. I have install in my Node.js directory the Thingdom ('neo4j') module in the directory, but when require('neo4j') prints an error.

[Image of my Node.js folder with Neo4j installed in modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GW1m.png)

```
var neo4j = require("neo4j");
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474");

var node = db.createNode({hello: 'world'});     // instantaneous, but...
node.save(function (err, node) {    // ...this is what actually persists.
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving new node to database:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Node saved to database with id:', node.id);
    }
});
```

And when using in the cmd: "node index.js" it throws me this error:

```
C:\Users\RRamos\Documents\Projects\test-neo4j>node index.js
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'neo4j'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RRamos\Documents\Projects\test-neo4j\index.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

Comment: It looks as if the module is installed as a global, that is not good. Install locally for the project.

Comment: I think is installed inside the project. You can look it in the image (Image of my Node.js folder with Neo4j installed in modules).

Comment: Thats right! I get you!, it seems it works now

Comment: I got the same problem, I installed `neo4j-driver` in the `web/` directory, but it should be one level higher, in the same directory as my `node.js` server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem. As there's no solution in this post, I just add mine.

After running `$ npm init` and `$ npm install --save neo4j-driver`, I copy and paste the [neo4j example code](https://neo4j.com/developer/) in **index.js**:

```
var neo4j = require("neo4j");
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:<password>@localhost:7474');
```

And then I got the same error when running `$ node index.js`.

In my **package.json**, I found:

```
"dependencies": {
    "neo4j-driver": "^1.1.0-M02"
}
```

It's `neo4j-driver` not `neo4j`. So replace it in **index.js**:

```
var neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:<password>@localhost:7474');
```

Now you will get rid of the `Cannot find module 'neo4j'` error!

---

In addition, if you use the 1.1.0 version of neo4j-driver(for Neo4j 3.0.0+), you may get this error:

```
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:<password>@localhost:7474');
         ^

TypeError: neo4j.GraphDatabase is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Codes\neo4j_test\server.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

It seems `neo4j.GraphDatabase` is only available in older version of neo4j-driver.

Here's [the up-to-date tutorial of neo4j-driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver).

Use the following code instead:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "<password>"));

// Create a session to run Cypher statements in.
// Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
var session = driver.session();

// Run a Cypher statement, reading the result in a streaming manner as records arrive:
session
  .run("MERGE (alice:Person {name : {nameParam} }) RETURN alice.name", { nameParam:'Alice' })
  .subscribe({
    onNext: function(record) {
     console.log(record._fields);
    },
    onCompleted: function() {
      // Completed!
      session.close();
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```